# Aligning markers and the limit symbol

Tags: horizontal-alignment, math-operators

I'm new here. I looked for questions that would help me with my problem, but I couldn't find it. In addition, my limited knowledge of Informatics does not help much. I apologize if you have already answered my question in another question or if it is something very basic.

How do I align the limit markers and symbols? If we analyze it calmly, we will see that the fourth limit is out of alignment because the "x tends to infinity" is much wider than the limit symbol itself. I would like to send all 5 limit symbols further to the right, so that they are all aligned. How can I do this?

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Solu\c{c}\~{o}es}

\begin{itemize}

\item $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{x^9-1}{x^5-1}=\frac{9.{1}^8}{5.{1}^4}=\frac{9}{5}$
\item $\lim\limits_{x\to {0}}\frac{e^{x}-1}{x^3}=\lim\limits_{x\to {0}}\frac{e^{x}}{3x^2}=+\infty$
\item $\lim\limits_{x\to {0}}\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}=\lim\limits_{x\to {0}}\frac{\cos x-1}{3x^2}=\lim\limits_{x\to {0}}\frac{-\sin x}{6x}=\lim\limits_{x\to {0}}\frac{-\cos x}{6}=-\frac{1}{6}$
\item $\lim\limits_{x\to {-\infty}}x^2e^x=\lim\limits_{x\to {-\infty}}\frac{x^2}{e^{-x}}=-2\lim\limits_{x\to {-\infty}}\frac{x}{e^{-x}}=2\lim\limits_{x\to {-\infty}}\frac{1}{e^{-x}}=0$
\item $\lim\limits_{x\to {0}}\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}=\lim\limits_{x\to {0}}\frac{e^x-1}{2x}=\lim\limits_{x\to {0}}\frac{e^x}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two ways of addressing the issue shown in item 4 of the list below:

- Load the `mathtools` package and use its `\mathclap` macro to assign the argument of `\lim` zero width -- see item 5 below. If you look closely, this adjustment actually goes a bit too far. Moreover, you've exchanged the imperfect-aligned issue with an `x\to`-sticks-out-to-left issue.
- Place the `-\infty` part of `\lim x\to-infty` in a `\parbox` of width `0`. See item 6 below. With this approach, the `lim` particle is aligned perfectly in rows 1 to 3 and 7.

Your derivation of the `\frac{9}{5}` result in the first item looks a bit fishy; in the code below, I've replaced with a derivation that employs L'Hopital's Rule. (I haven't gone through your other derivations.) Oh, and I would typeset all math parts in the list in `\displaystyle` math mode, in order to generate displaystyle-size fraction terms.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \mathclap macro
\usepackage{calc}      % for \widthof macro
\begin{document}

\textbf{Solu\c{c}\~{o}es}
\begin{enumerate}
\everymath{\displaystyle} % <-- optional
\item $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^9-1}{x^5-1}=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{9x^8}{5x^4}=\frac{9}{5}$
\item $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{x}-1}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{x}}{3x^2}=+\infty$
\item $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos x-1}{3x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-\sin x}{6x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-\cos x}{6}=-\frac{1}{6}$
\item $\lim_{x\to -\infty}x^2e^x=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{x^2}{e^{-x}}=-2\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{x}{e^{-x}}=2\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{1}{e^{-x}}=0$
\item $\lim_{\mathclap{x\to -\infty}}x^2e^x=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{x^2}{e^{-x}}=-2\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{x}{e^{-x}}=2\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{1}{e^{-x}}=0$
\item $\lim_{x\to\parbox{\widthof{\scriptsize$0$}}{\scriptsize$-\infty$}}x^2e^x=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{x^2}{e^{-x}}=-2\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{x}{e^{-x}}=2\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{1}{e^{-x}}=0$
\item $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{2x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir @Mico.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps I overinterpreted the OP's question, but it seemed to me there was a desire for full alignment across all columns.  If that is so, that I suggest replacing the `itemize` with a tabbed math environment or macro.  In this case, I chose `\tabbedCenterstack` of the `tabstackengine` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsfonts,mathtools,tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\TABstackMathstyle{\displaystyle}
\begin{document}
\textbf{Solu\c{c}\~{o}es}

\begingroup
\edef~{~\,}
\setstackgap{L}{35pt}
\def\item{\bullet~}
\TABbinary
\medskip
~\tabbedCenterstack[l]{
\item& \lim_{\mathclap{x\to 1}}\frac{x^9-1}{x^5-1}
  &=\frac{9.{1}^8}{5.{1}^4}
  &=\frac{9}{5}
  &
  &\\
\item &\lim_{\mathclap{x\to {0}}}\frac{e^{x}-1}{x^3}
  &=\lim_{\mathclap{x\to {0}}}\frac{e^{x}}{3x^2}
  &=+\infty
  &
  &\\
\item &\lim_{\mathclap{x\to {0}}}\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}
  &=\lim_{\mathclap{x\to {0}}}\frac{\cos x-1}{3x^2}
  &=\phantom{-2}\lim_{\mathclap{x\to {0}}}\frac{-\sin x}{6x}
  &=\phantom{2}\lim_{\mathclap{x\to {0}}}\frac{-\cos x}{6}
  &=-\frac{1}{6}\\
\item& \lim_{\mathclap{x\to {-\infty}}}~x^2e^x
  &=\lim_{\mathclap{x\to {-\infty}}}~\frac{x^2}{e^{-x}}
  &=-2\lim_{\mathclap{x\to {-\infty}}}~\frac{x}{e^{-x}}
  &=2\lim_{\mathclap{x\to {-\infty}}}~\frac{1}{e^{-x}}
  &=0\\
\item& \lim_{\mathclap{x\to {0}}}\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}
  &=\lim_{\mathclap{x\to {0}}}\frac{e^x-1}{2x}
  &=\phantom{-2}\lim_{\mathclap{x\to {0}}}\frac{e^x}{2}
  &=\frac{1}{2}
  &
}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much sir @Steven.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\mathclap` from `mathtools` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,amsfonts}

\usepackage{mathtools}% \mathclap

\begin{document}

\textbf{Solu\c{c}\~{o}es}

\begin{itemize}

\item $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{x^9-1}{x^5-1}=\frac{9.{1}^8}{5.{1}^4}=\frac{9}{5}$
\item $\lim\limits_{x\to {0}}\frac{e^{x}-1}{x^3}=\lim\limits_{x\to {0}}\frac{e^{x}}{3x^2}=+\infty$
\item $\lim\limits_{x\to {0}}\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}=\lim\limits_{x\to {0}}\frac{\cos x-1}{3x^2}=\lim\limits_{x\to {0}}\frac{-\sin x}{6x}=\lim\limits_{x\to {0}}\frac{-\cos x}{6}=-\frac{1}{6}$
\item $\lim\limits_{x\to {-\infty}}x^2e^x=\lim\limits_{x\to {-\infty}}\frac{x^2}{e^{-x}}=-2\lim\limits_{x\to {-\infty}}\frac{x}{e^{-x}}=2\lim\limits_{x\to {-\infty}}\frac{1}{e^{-x}}=0$
\item $\lim\limits_{x\to {0}}\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}=\lim\limits_{x\to {0}}\frac{e^x-1}{2x}=\lim\limits_{x\to {0}}\frac{e^x}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$

\item $\lim\limits_{
  \mathclap{x\to {-\infty}}% center and take zero width
}x^2e^x=\lim\limits_{x\to {-\infty}}\frac{x^2}{e^{-x}}=-2\lim\limits_{x\to {-\infty}}\frac{x}{e^{-x}}=2\lim\limits_{x\to {-\infty}}\frac{1}{e^{-x}}=0$

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir @ivankolan.